# Graph of x^y = 5

Tags: logarithms

can we have a graph where y = log base x (5) ? or x^y = 5 ?

When I draw this graph out it has a horizontal asymptote at x = 0 on the right end, and it has values in the negative x-axis from -5 < x < -1

Edit : I'm just picking up graphs of logarithms and was wondering if there can be a graph of y = log base x (5), since I havent seen those examples yet

Comment: What exactly do you want?

Comment: you can definitely graph this relationship! https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ax8hw2c5gh

Comment: @danimal How did you manage to get a link of that particular function?

Comment: you can make an account on desmos, plot the graph you want (look at the right hand bar) and then just share (top left icons)

Comment: @danimal Thanks!!

Comment: @danimal nice! shouldn't there however be values from -5< x < -1 and -1< x < 0 though?

Comment: not for the log relationship, as the log of a negative number is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x^y=5 \\ y\cdot\ln(x)=\ln(5) \\ y=\dfrac{\ln(5)}{\ln(x)}=\dfrac{\text{constant}}{\ln(x)} $$

This function is easily analyzed by derivatives and graphical methods. It has a vertical asymptote at $x=1$ and approaches $0$ as $x\to0$. Rough graph:
[image: Rough graph of y]
The derivative of the function approaches $-\infty$ as $x\to 0$. Actual graph (from WolframAlpha):
[image: Actual graph of y]
Note the tendency of graph to become vertical near $x=0$.

Comment: ah thanks! and as the value increases , lets say from 5 to 10, the two slopes of the graph deviate further and further away from the point (1,0)? Neat property

Comment: @BrotundWasser What do you mean by "the two slopes of the graph"?

Comment: I meant the curved portion of the graph. that means the curved section moves away from the point (1,0). As the value increases to 10, when y = 1, x must be 10 (further away)

Comment: @BrotundWasser Oh okay, I got you now! Yes it does. The graph "moves" both up, and right. But note that, in both your cases, $y$ never becomes zero, even though it does get closer and closer! So graph doesn't really move, it somehow "stretches" upward and rightward. Had it moved, it would mean $y$ would never come close to zero, but it does. Keep observing and thinking like this! It opens your mind and helps a lot in learning! :)